# Open new page on keystroke

Tags: jquery

I really like the search-functionality on the New Myspace, where a user can start typing in a artistname and the search opens up immediately.

Does anyone know about such a jQuery-plugin? I have yet to find one through Google :l

Comment: What does Google say?

Comment: Nothing.... As I stated just above ;)

Comment: Are you wanting a physical new page or something like Google where when you start typing, the layout changes and search results are instantly shown above. The reason I'm asking is that the latter (Google approach) uses ajax to load the content automatically without opening a new page.

Comment: I want a ajax solution like Google and Myspace. However I think Myspace uses an overlay as if I exit I get back to the page I where on before I started typing anything

Comment: Why do people vote down this one? It should be a pretty simple answer...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [jquery-ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Thats quite a big library, as I dont use it at the moment. Doesnt it only give me autocomplete?